# How to not include the author name in the first short author print?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, author

When I work with the shortauthor command, the first shortauthor print in text looks like that: ..... (author [shortauthor], year).

The following short author prints with the same reference looks like that:
..... (shortauthor, year)

I would like for my printed citation in the text only the shortauthor (as defined in my bibliography) to be displayed --> (shortauthor, year)
I dont't want the full author in the first print.

My citation in the literature:

```
    @techreport{BMU2020,
    author = {{BMU \& BfN - Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit und Bundesamt für Naturschutz}},
    shortauthor = {{BMU \& BFN}},
    file = {:Users/lucafuchs/Documents/Polybox/Masterarbeit Literatur und Bilder/Literatur/Jugendliche und Umwelt/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf:pdf},
    keywords = {Bundesministerium f{\"{u}}r Umwelt,Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020: Bev{\"{o}}lkerungsumfrage,Naturschutz und biologische Vielfalt,Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit (BMU),www.bmu.de},
    title = {{Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020}},
    url = {https://www.bmu.de/fileadmin/Daten_BMU/Pools/Broschueren/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf},
    year = {2020}
    }
```

In my recompiled pdf it shows this for my first citation:

> .... Heranwachsenden eine zentrale Rolle einnimmt” (BMU & BfN - Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit und Bundesamt für Naturschutz[BMU & BFN], 2020, p. 27.)

But I actually want my first print to look like this:

> .... Heranwachsenden eine zentrale Rolle einnimmt” (BMU & BfN, 2020, p. 27.)

I am using biblatex - That's my input in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
sorting=aynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citep \cite
\let \citet \textcite
\let \cite \parencite
```

And here's my working example:

```
 \documentclass[
    oneside,
    11pt, 
    %oneside,
    ngerman, 
    singlespacing, 
    %draft, 
    %nolistspacing, 
    %liststotoc, 
    %toctotoc, 
    %parskip, 
    %nohyperref, 
    headsepline, 
    ]{Class File} 
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
    \usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{color,soul}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{bibgerm}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% deutsche Trennregeln
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% wichtig für Trennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
    \usepackage{microtype}% verbesserter Randausgleich
    
    %UNTEN FüR AUFLISTUNGEN
    \usepackage{enumitem} 
    \newlist{titemize}{itemize}{1}% neue Listenumgebung für Tabellen
    \setlist[titemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep,label=-}
    
    %Tables
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %Paragraphen werden nicht eingesetzt
    
    \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
    sorting=aynt
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Literature.bib}
    
    % maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
    \let \citep \cite
    \let \citet \textcite
    \let \cite \parencite
    
    \providecommand{\shortcite}[1]{\cite{#1}}
    
    
    \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
    
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   MARGIN SETTINGS
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \geometry{
        paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
        inner=2.3cm, % Inner margin
        outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
        bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
        top=1.9cm, % Top margin
        bottom=2.2cm, % Bottom margin
        %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
    }
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   THESIS INFORMATION
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ...
    
    \AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
    \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
    }
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    % Tables are small now 
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    % Tables are small now 
    \floatsetup[table]{font=small}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages
    
    \pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Graphics/eth_logo.eps} %\includegraphics{eth_logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it
    
    \vspace*{.06\textheight}
    
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\Large Master-Arbeit}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type
    \end{center}
    
    \HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
    {\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
    \HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line
     
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
    \emph{Verfasser:}\\
    {\authorname}
    
    \addressname
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
    \emph{Referent:} \\
    {\supname} \\
    \emph{Koreferent:}\\
    Florian \textsc{Knaus}\\
    \end{flushright}\\
    \end{minipage}\\[3cm]
    
    \vfill
    
    \large \textit{\degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
    \textit{}\\[0.4cm]
    \groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name
     
    \vfill
    
    {\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
     
    \vfill
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    %   FOREWORD PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \chapter*{Vorwort}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vorwort}
    ....
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ABSTRACT PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    \chapter*{Zusammenfassung}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Zusammenfassung}

    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TABLE OF CONTENTS
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables % Prints the list of tables
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ABBREVIATIONS
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)
    
    \textbf{BAFU} - Bundesamt für Umwelt - Schweiz\\
    \textbf{BfN} - Bundesamt für Naturschutz - Deutschland\\
    \textbf{BMU} - Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und Nukleare Sicherheit - Deutschland\\
    \textbf{BR} - Biosphärenreservat \\
    \textbf{UBE} - UNESCO Biosphäre Entlebuch\\
    \textbf{WSL} - Eidgenössiche Forschungsanstalt für Wald, Schnee und Landschaft\\
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    
    \end{abbreviations}
    \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    %   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
 %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    \mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
    
    \pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style
   
    \include{Chapters/00_Einleitung}
    \include{Chapters/01_Forschungsstand und theoretische Grundlagen} 
    \include{Chapters/02_Forschungsdesign und Methode}
    \include{Chapters/03_Resultate}
    \include{Chapters/04_Diskussion} 
    \include{Chapters/05_Fazit}
    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices
    \include{Appendices/Eigenständigkeitserklärung}
    \include{Appendices/Soziodemographische Merkmale Teilnehmer:innen}
    \include{Appendices/Interviewleitfaden}
    \include{Appendices/Transkriptionsleitfaden}
    \include{Appendices/Kodierleitfaden}
    \include{Appendices/Kategorienhandbuch}
    
    % Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
    % Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices
    
    %\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
    %\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    %   BIBLIOGRAPHY
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}
    \raggedright
    \printbibliography
    \bibliographystyle{plain.bst}
    
    \end{document}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited it my question

Comment: You need to provide a *lot* more information, and a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) (read link). I assume you're using biblatex from the tags (though you didn't say so in your post), but what style are you using, and what other settings?

Comment: I tried to do so. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect can be reproduced in the following minimal example

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{BMU2020,
  author      = {{BMU \& BfN -- Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit
                 und Bundesamt für Naturschutz}},
  shortauthor = {{BMU \& BFN}},
  title       = {{Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020}},
  url         = {https://www.bmu.de/fileadmin/Daten_BMU/Pools/Broschueren/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf},
  year        = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{BMU2020}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{BMU2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It is my understanding that if you modify your example a tiny bit to

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{BMU2020,
  author      = {{Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit
                 und Bundesamt für Naturschutz}},
  shortauthor = {{BMU \& BFN}},
  title       = {{Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020}},
  url         = {https://www.bmu.de/fileadmin/Daten_BMU/Pools/Broschueren/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf},
  year        = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{BMU2020}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{BMU2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you'd get the output that APA style wants (see https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date).

If you don't actually want APA style, it is usually best not to use `style=apa,` it's better to stick to a standard style like `style=authoryear,` since the standard styles are much easier to customise.

That said, with the following code you can always force `style=apa,` to show only the `shortauthor`

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved\@firstoftwo
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{BMU2020,
  author      = {{BMU \& BFN --
                  Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit
                 und Bundesamt für Naturschutz}},
  shortauthor = {{BMU \& BFN}},
  title       = {{Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020}},
  url         = {https://www.bmu.de/fileadmin/Daten_BMU/Pools/Broschueren/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf},
  year        = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{BMU2020}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{BMU2020}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (BMU & BFN, 2020) ipsum (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) dolor (BMU & BFN, 2020) BMU & BFN – Bundesministerium für Umwelt, Naturschutz und nukleare Sicherheit und Bundesamt für Naturschutz. (2020). Jugend-Naturbewusstsein 2020 (Techn. Ber.). https://www.bmu.de/fileadmin/Daten_BMU/Pools/Broschueren/jugend-naturbewusstsein_2020.pdf Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P]

Comment: Thank you so much! It has worked perfectly! :)

Comment: @LucaFuchs If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark icon on the top left. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. That way the question is marked as answered.